# Change sequence of navigationcontroller iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created a iphone app using navigation controller from app wizard.

i have 3 views. say view 1, view 2, view 3

view 1 is landing screen.

i go to view 2 from view 1 and to view 3 from view 2 [button click]

In view 3 I want to come back to view 1 when I click back button on navigation control

is it possible ? How do i do that ? [I know by default it comes back to view 2]

Again on click of a button in view 3 i need to show a view 2 with other information [both are same viewcontroller class.] I cann not do a new viewcontroller 2 nd push, because again my traversal will go through view 2 -> view 3 -> view 2 -> view 1. I want the behaviour as in view 3 when i press a button i get view 2 with another similar item information and when press back there, come to view 2

please advise right way to do this

Answer (score 2):

*Probelm 1:*

On clicking the back button you should call `[self.navigationController popToRootViewController]`.

One more thing to note here is that you can not modify the behavior of default `backButtonItem`. You have to create a button and assign it as `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.

*Problem 2:*

I don't think it will be a good idea to push View 2 again when you click a button on View 3. Keep single View 2 and do some conditions checking to show different content. For example if you come from View 1, show the default content, but if you are coming back from View 3 show different content.

Comment: thanks, that will probably solve problem 1. how to solve problem 2 ? view 3 yields me view 2 with different item than earlier and back of that will go to view 1 ?